# group law on cubic curves.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

I have been reading my lecture notes, and I am stuck on this part.
It states

"Let $C \subset \mathbb{P}^2_K$. We define on $C$ an abelian structure.

Take points $P$ and $Q$ on $C$ and pass a line through P and
Q. Denote by $P ∗ Q$ the 3rd point of intersection of the line with $C$ "

, why is it automatic assumed that it will pass through a third point of the cubic curve. Is there some type of lemma I have missed.

Comment: I don't think this is obvious at all. You need something like Bezout's theorem for this.

Comment: I see! You will need Bezotu's thm in the projective plane in projective space. Thanks! We have not proved or stated this in our course. Not sure why he left this out!